# Get all Parameters as List

Tags: r

Does R provide an object/function/method/keyword to get all function arguments?

Using an example:
`function(a, b="default", ...)` would provide `a` and `b` as well as `...` within the function environment. Is there a statement similar to `list(...)` that would also include `a` and `b` in the result?

Or put yet another way: a shorthand for `list(a=a, b=b, ...)`, given `function(a, b, ...)`

Comment: The problem of this question is that it is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to get 1)  the *values* with which the function was called; 2) the *expressions* with which the function was called; 3) the *default values* in the function definition? It's not clear at all from your question, so you got 3 different types of answers for all of these 3 options.

Comment: Agreed. The question is ambiguous and the answers are thus unhelpful.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think that you want `match.call`:

```
tmpfun <- function(a,b,...) {
print(as.list(match.call()))
print(as.list(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)))
}
> tmpfun(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
[[1]]
tmpfun

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3

$d
[1] 4

[[1]]
tmpfun

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$...
$...$c
[1] 3

$...$d
[1] 4
```

Comment: This fails if the defaults are not overridden in the function call. It won't list the argument with the default set but not overridden.

Comment: Are you aware of a package that exports such a function (with only `...` as parameter)?

Comment: This doesn't work when tmpfun received arguments from another wrapper function. (the list has only the non evaluated arguments)

Comment: For these reasons, the accepted answer should be the one from @user399470 that uses  `c(as.list(environment()), list(...))` which captures both default args and supplied args.

Answer (score 105):

One solution is to use:

```
tempf <- function(a, b = 2, ...) {
    argg <- c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
    print(argg)
}
tempf(1, c = 3)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

This creates a named list of the argument values.

Comment: Are you aware of a package that exports such a function (with only `...` as parameter)?

Comment: or simply print(as.list(environment())) if you don't have ... as argument

Comment: This works great, it has the advantage over the accepted answer that it captures the *values* passed to the function, rather than the *expressions* that can be used to compute the values.  If you're trying to save the args so you can call the function later, you probably want the values.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that it's usually important to "capture" the arguments by running `argg <- c(as.list(environment()), list(...))` at the very beginning of your function. Otherwise, `environment()` will end up including other variables that are created within `tempf()`

Answer (score 19):

try `args` function

What are the arguments for `mean` function?

```
> args(mean)
function (x, ...) 
NULL
```

What about `lm` function?

```
    > args(lm)
function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) 
NULL
```

If you want to get a list of arguments try

```
as.list(args(lm))
```

Comment: It's to bad more functions don't cooperate with the args call such as predict.  So humbug to have to go elsewhere to remember that one parameter/flag that you were trying to remember.

Answer (score 14):

Stumbled upon this question while searching for something related. While I realize that this is several years old, the responses appear unsatisfactory, and there does not appear to be any off-the-shelf solution to the question.

It is possible to make an (inelegant) workaround, using a combination of the `formals` and `environment` functions. The example below extracts arguments from the environment using names extracted from formals, then appends the ellipsis-list. If you wish to have the values as they were set at the time of function call, set the orig_values argument to TRUE. The function only includes variables implicitly or explicitly set at function call.

```
allargs <- function(orig_values = FALSE) {
  # get formals for parent function
  parent_formals <- formals(sys.function(sys.parent(n = 1)))

  # Get names of implied arguments
  fnames <- names(parent_formals)

  # Remove '...' from list of parameter names if it exists
  fnames <- fnames[-which(fnames == '...')]

  # Get currently set values for named variables in the parent frame
  args <- evalq(as.list(environment()), envir = parent.frame())

  # Get the list of variables defined in '...'
  args <- c(args[fnames], evalq(list(...), envir = parent.frame()))


  if(orig_values) {
    # get default values
    defargs <- as.list(parent_formals)
    defargs <- defargs[unlist(lapply(defargs, FUN = function(x) class(x) != "name"))]
    args[names(defargs)] <- defargs
    setargs <- evalq(as.list(match.call())[-1], envir = parent.frame())
    args[names(setargs)] <- setargs
  }
  return(args)
}


tempf <- function(a, b = 2, ...) {
  d <- 5
  b <- 3

  cat("Currently set values defined in call or formals\n")
  print(allargs())
  cat("Values as defined at the time of the call\n")
  print(allargs(T))
}

tempf(1, c = 3)

Currently set values defined in call or formals
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 3

Values as defined at the time of the call
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are looking for `formals`:

```
formals(sd)
$x


$na.rm
[1] FALSE
```

And using `dput` on this gives you the form you specify in the question:

```
dput(formals(sd))
list(x = , na.rm = FALSE)
```

Note that `formals` doesn't work for *primitive* functions, only closures.

Comment: this only lists the _default_ arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`rlang::fn_fmls` gives a brief and clean solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

# action
argument_list <- rlang::fn_fmls(fn = geom_point)

# evaluate output
class(argument_list)
#> [1] "pairlist"

is.list(argument_list)
#> [1] TRUE

argument_list
#> $mapping
#> NULL
#> 
#> $data
#> NULL
#> 
#> $stat
#> [1] "identity"
#> 
#> $position
#> [1] "identity"
#> 
#> $...
#> 
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $show.legend
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $inherit.aes
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The function by @Intelligentaccident was almost exactly what I was after. The only problem I had was some functions I needed it for had `...`'s and others didn't. I have made his code even more inelegant (actually, I thought it was pretty clear and well commented) in order to work with both types of function. Thanks so much @Intelligentaccident your code has made my life much easier.

```
allargs <- function(orig_values = FALSE) {
  # get formals for parent function
  parent_formals <- formals(sys.function(sys.parent(n = 1)))
  
  # Get names of implied arguments
  fnames <- names(parent_formals)
  
  # Remove '...' from list of parameter names if it exists
  fnames <- fnames[which(fnames != '...')]
  
  # Get currently set values for named variables in the parent frame
  args <- evalq(as.list(environment()), envir = parent.frame())[fnames]
  

  # Get the list of variables defined in '...'
  if (any(names(parent_formals) == '...')) args <- c(args,evalq(list(...), envir = parent.frame()))
  
  if(orig_values) {
    # get default values
    defargs <- as.list(parent_formals)
    defargs <- defargs[unlist(lapply(defargs, FUN = function(x) class(x) != "name"))]
    args[names(defargs)] <- defargs
    setargs <- evalq(as.list(match.call())[-1], envir = parent.frame())
    args[names(setargs)] <- setargs
  }
  return(args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test <- function(
  x = 1,
  y = 2,
  ...
) {
  if(length(list(...)) == 0) {
    print(as.list(environment()))
  } else {
    print(c(as.list(environment()), list(...)))
  }
}

test()
test(z = 3)
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of using this method over the solutions already proposed? In particular, this seems to be extremely similar to the answer by user399470