# Use match.call to pass all arguments to other function

Tags: r, arguments, parameter-passing

From `?match.call`:

> `match.call` is most commonly used in two circumstances:
>   […] To pass most of the call to another function […]

After reading that, I expected I could use `match.call` when I want to pass all arguments of one function to another function without listing these arguments one by one.

Example: `outer1` passes arguments one by one, `outer2` uses `match.call`.

```
outer1 <- function(a, b, c) {
  inner1(a, b, c)
}

inner1 <- function(a, b, c) { 
  return(a + b + c$first + c$second)
}

outer2 <- function(a, b, c) {
   mycall <- match.call()
   inner2(mycall)
}

inner2 <- function(call) {
   return(call$a + call$b + call$c$first + call$c$second)
}

outer1(1, 2, list(first = 3, second = 4)) # OK: 10
outer2(1, 2, list(first = 3, second = 4)) # OK: 10
```

The first problem arises, when `-1` instead of `1` is passed to `outer2`:

```
outer2(-1, 2, list(first = 3, second = 4)) # Error in call$a + call$b : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**Question 1**: What is the technical difference between passing `-1` instead of `1`? I know that

```
typeof(quote(1)) # double
typeof(quote(-1)) # language
```

but I suppose that the fact that I  passed a `language` object in the second case is not the (only) relevant difference because passing something of type language to argument `c` works (`typeof(quote(list(first = 3, second = 4))) # language`).

In order to overcome the problem above, I try to `eval` all arguments that are of type `language`:

```
outer3 <- function(a, b, c) {

parsedCall <- lapply(match.call()[-1L], FUN=function(argument) {
    if(is.language(argument)) {
      return(eval(argument))
    } else {
      return(argument)
    }
  })

  inner3(parsedCall)
}

inner3 <- function(parsedCall) {  
  return(parsedCall$a + parsedCall$b + parsedCall$c$first + parsedCall$c$second)
}

outer3(-1, 2, list(first = 3, second = 4)) # OK: 8
```

**Question 2:** The approach in `outer3` seems to "work" but are there further pitfalls I need to take into account? (I know that in some cases it might be disadvantageous to evaluate the arguments but for my case this should not be an issue.)

**Question 3:** I suppose that the desire to pass all arguments to another function is not very uncommon. Is there a better/standard approach than what I did?

**Question 4:** Is it advantageous to pass the raw `call` to the inner function an do the `eval` stuff there? Would this be helpful if I would like to have the arguments as local variables in the `inner` functions (instead of elements of the `parsedCall` list)? Then, the body of `inner3` could be identical to the body of `inner1` (while with the current solution, I have to replace `a+b` with `parsedCall$a + parsedCall$b`).

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. Regarding your first question: I believe `-1` is a call to the unary minus function (see `help("-"))`, i.e., equivalent to ``;`-`(1)`` (`;` added to render this correctly). `1` is not a function call, but simply a double value. (I'm not sure if `-1` would be function call without wrapping it in quote. It might be parsed as a double value then.)

Comment: Tanks for your remarks on my first question, Roland. Regarding "one question per post": While I was writing the question I wondered if it's OK to include several "sub-questions" in one question and then decided to do so because all my questions are closely related to the "main question" – in fact, they only focus on different aspects. In the meantime I found a different approach: Get a list of all evaluated arguments, and pass it to the inner function using `do.call` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17244041/2706569).

Answer (score 8):

Regarding your question:

> I suppose that the desire to pass all arguments to another function is
> not very uncommon. Is there a better/standard approach than what I
> did?

Then I would say this is a more common way to pass the arguments on:

```r
inner1 <- function(a, b, c) { 
  return(a + b + c$first + c$second)
}

outer3 <- function(a, b, c) {
  mycall <- match.call()
  mycall[[1]] <- as.symbol("inner1") # use inner 1
  eval(mycall)
}

outer4 <- function(a, b, c) {
  .args <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  do.call(inner1, .args)
}

outer3(-1, 2, list(first = 3, second = 4))
#R> [1] 8

outer4(-1, 2, list(first = 3, second = 4))
#R> [1] 8
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Would you mind explaining the differences between your approach in `outer3` vs. `outer4`? From a readability point of view I tend to prefer `outer4`, but are there technical differences to take into account?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. Neither seems to evaluate the arguments if it is not needed and they both evaluate the `parent.frame()` as the environment.