# Collecting all function arguments in R

Tags: r

Naively, I thought that R's ... notation would collect all named arguments that appear after it so that they can be passed along. For example:

```
> a <- function(..., arg=TRUE) b(...)
> b <- function(arg=TRUE) print(arg)
> a(arg=FALSE)
[1] TRUE # I would want this to be FALSE
```

Since this clearly doesn't happen, is there some way to package up all of the arguments supplied to a function so that they get sent along?

Comment: How about `a <- function(...){ 
      b(...)
}`

Comment: Probably [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions)

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17244041/354979) helps

Comment: @akrun I want `a` to have default values

Comment: "arg" is not part of argument "..." of `a` which is passed to `b`.  Depending on your use case, you might find `match.call` useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all Parameters as List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885207/get-all-parameters-as-list)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass `arg`:

```
a <- function(..., arg=TRUE) b(..., arg = arg)
```

Comment: And if I have 100 arguments? I need to retype all of them?

Comment: Well designed functions don't have 100 arguments.