# how can I pass argument (names) to a function factory?

Tags: r, functional-programming, closures, factory

I need to build a lot of functions with lots of different arguments, though they otherwise share a lot of code and structure. 
To avoid duplication, I thought I'd be clever and build myself a function factory (aka closure).

**I can't figure out how to pass the function arguments inside the function factory**.

My use case is a bunch of S3 constructor functions, all of which share the same validation mechanism.
So I'll use that as an example to explain my problem.

Say, I have a `ClassA` and `ClassB`, each of which require their own arguments in the respective constructor functions:

```
ClassA <- function(A_arg1, A_arg2) {
  # some class-SPECIFIC construction magic happens, say
  out <- list(A_arg1, A_arg2)

  # some GENERAL construction magic happens
  class(out) <- "ClassA"

  return(out)
}

ClassB <- function(B_arg1, B_arg2) {
  # some class-SPECIFIC construction magic happens, say
  out <- B_arg1 + B_arg2

  # some GENERAL construction magic happens
  class(out) <- "ClassB"

  return(out)
}
```

Obviously, I'd love to avoid the duplication in the *general* part of the constructor functions, so a function factory that *could be used like so* would be nice:

```
ClassA <- produce_class_constructor(classname = "ClassA", fun = function(A_arg1, A_arg2) {return(list(A_arg1, A_arg2))})
```

This should, ideally, yield the exact same function as the above manually constructed `ClassA` function, with the general part factored out.

**Here's my attempt at building that function factory**:

```
produce_class_constructor <- function(classname, fun) {
  class_specific_arguments <- formals(fun = fun)  # this works just fine on the console
  construct_class <- function(class_specific_arguments) {
    # here runs the class-specific stuff
    out <- fun(class_specific_arguments)

    # here runs the general stuff
    class(out) <- classname
  }
}
```

This however, does not work, because the resulting constructor function only has a `class_specific_arguments`-argument, not the, well, actual `A_arg1`, and `A_arg2`.

Is there way to do this?
Am I doing this wrong?

(It's really important to me that the resulting class constructor functions have properly named arguments, so a `...` approach won't work).

Comment: I added a similar question, where I'm trying to figure out how to [solve the same problem with function operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923632/how-can-i-pass-argument-names-to-a-function-operator-point-free-programming) aka *point-free* functional programming. Maybe more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
produce_class_constructor <- function(classname, fun) {
  out_fun <- function() {
    out_obj <- do.call(fun, as.list(environment()))
    class(out_obj) <- classname
    out_obj
  }
  formals(out_fun) <- formals(fun)
  out_fun
}

ClassA <- produce_class_constructor(classname = "ClassA", 
  fun = function(A_arg1, A_arg2) {list(A_arg1, A_arg2)})
ClassA(1, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "ClassA"

ClassB <- produce_class_constructor(classname = "ClassB", 
  fun = function(B_arg1, B_arg2) {B_arg1 + B_arg2})
ClassB(B_arg2 = 2, 1)
#[1] 3
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "ClassB"
```

Idea with `as.list(environment())` taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885207/get-all-parameters-as-list). Note that you should be extra careful along that path, as `?formals` says, "this is
advanced, dangerous coding".

Comment: ah fantastic, thanks so much, this get's the job done.

Do you @tonytonov or anyone else know *why* this is considered "dangerous" and/or have another, safer suggestion to get this done?

Comment: @maxheld You're welcome. Well, it's not super dangerous so far, but the point is, messing with `body` and `formals` is not a trivial thing. It's obsure: show me this snippet next week and I probably won't understand its purpose. It's difficult to maintain and you may expect some quirks at a later development stage (say, additional work will be required if you need `...` support in constructors, etc.). Doesn't mean this road is bad; for tasks like yours this is fine, just don't try to implement your own fully object-oriented class system :)