# how can I pass argument (names) to a function operator? (point-free programming)

Tags: r, validation, functional-programming, closures, pointfree

#### Background

Say, I have a `ClassA` and `ClassB`, each of which require their own arguments in the respective constructor functions:

```
ClassA <- function(A_arg1, A_arg2) {
  # some class-SPECIFIC construction magic happens, say
  out <- list(A_arg1, A_arg2)

  # some GENERAL construction magic happens
  class(out) <- "ClassA"

  return(out)
}

ClassB <- function(B_arg1, B_arg2) {
  # some class-SPECIFIC construction magic happens, say
  out <- B_arg1 + B_arg2

  # some GENERAL construction magic happens
  class(out) <- "ClassB"

  return(out)
}
```

My actual use case is a bit more complicated; I'm trying to use constructor and `check.ClassName()` methods to shoehorn type validation into `S3`.

#### Motivation

Obviously, I'd love to avoid the duplication in the *general* part of the above constructor functions, so a function factory that *could be used like so* would be nice:

```
ClassA <- produce_class_constructor(classname = "ClassA", fun = function(A_arg1, A_arg2) {return(list(A_arg1, A_arg2))})
```

This should, ideally, yield the exact same function as the above manually constructed `ClassA` function, with the general part factored out.
(The general part in my real use case is quite a bit longer).

**Caveat**: It's crucial that the factory-produced `ClassA()` constructor *retain the argument names* (here `A_arg1`, `A_arg2`), so that documentation and autocomplete can guide the user in construction.

I want to use best functional programming (FP) practices to solve this problem.

I've [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695298/how-can-i-pass-argument-names-to-a-function-factory) about doing this via a simple *closure*, but I know wonder whether doing this via [**function operators**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html) might not be a better way, where I simply wrap (or `compose`) the general operators around the particular pieces for each class to yield a constructor function for each class.

In **pseudocode**, I'd like to design something like this:

```
produce_class_constructor <- function(classname, fun) {
  class_constructor_func <- validate_class(append_class(classname, fun()))
}
```

where, `append_class()` makes the custom `fun` also append some class, and `validate_class()` in turn also makes the custom `fun` run checks on its results.

I could then use this constructor function factor to elegantly create, say, the above `ClassA()`:

```
    ClassA <- produce_class_constructor(classname = "ClassA", fun = function(A_arg1, A_arg2) {return(list(A_arg1, A_arg2))})
```

#### Attempt

Here's my simple (failing) attempt.

```
# simple helper to append classes
append_class <- function(obj, classname) {
  class(obj) <- append(class(obj), classname)
  return(obj)
}

produce_class_constructor <- function(classname, fun) {
  force(fun)  # not sure what this does, but seems to be necessary as per http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html

  # all the GENERAL construction magic from above now happens here
  class_constructor_fun <- function(...) {
    append_class(classname, fun(...))
  }
  formals(class_constructor_fun) <- formals(fun)  # this is necessary to carry over argument names

  return(class_constructor_fun)
}

ClassB <- produce_class_constructor(classname = "ClassB", fun = function(B_arg1, B_arg2) {
  # this is the class-SPECIFIC construction magic from above
  out <- B_arg1 + B_arg2
  return(out)
})

ClassB(B_arg1 = 1, B_arg2 = 2)  # this fails
```

The good news is that the resulting `ClassB()` has named arguments.

The bad news is that they don't get passed along, and the whole thing fails with:

```
 Error in append(class(obj), classname) : 
  '...' used in an incorrect context
```

#### Question(s)

1. Is this a sound "point-free" FP design and an ok/good idea generally?
2. If yes, how can I fix my attempt? (= make the "inner" function aware of its arguments)
3. If not, what would be the "proper" FP way of doing this?
4. (Bonus): Is there already a package out there that shoehorns this kind of validation and rigour into `S3`? (other OOs are not an option and scare my pants off).

Comment: For most practical applications when people are talking about point-free programming they are talking about composing unary functions. I'm not sure your question makes that much sense... nor is it clear what the point-free style would buy you here.