# Get all names of ... function arguments in R

Tags: r, function, parameters, arguments

I am trying to find all the names of the `...` argument of a R function from within R; without checking source code.

For instance:

```
library(DBI)

formals(DBI::dbConnect)
```

Outputs:

```
$drv


$...
```

Or

```
args(DBI::dbConnect)
```

Outputs:

```
function (drv, ...) 
NULL
```

How do I get all the parameter names within `...`?

EDIT:

Tried match call:

```
match.call(formals(DBI::dbConnect))
```

Output:

```
match.call(drv = DBI::dbConnect)
```

Comment: use `match.call`? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885207/get-all-parameters-as-list ... so something like this: `test <- function(x, ...) names(as.list(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE))$"...")`

Comment: Its trivial to do when you are writing code within the function itself, in this case I want to be able to pass a function as an argument and find all the names of the arguments to that function including the names in the dots ```...```

Comment: `...` can be passed on to other functions within the original function. unless if you read the documentation or code, you will not be able to tell what other functions is being used or what arguments these other functions are expecting