# How to get number of arguments of a closure in R

Tags: r, function, introspection

I have function in variable:

```
foo <- function(a, b) {}
```

I can use:

```
body(foo)
```

to the the source code for the function, I can use this:

```
length(substitute(function(a, b) {})[[2]])
```

but only if I put function inline. So how can I get number of arguments to a function?

I've also tried

```
length(foo)
# 1
```

so this don't work. I want to write function that will work with handlers that can have 1 or 2 arguments, so I've though of writing general utility:

```
#' Function call function fn with the only arguments it accept
invoke <- function(fn, ...) {
  if (!is.function(fn)) {
    stop("invoke: argument need to be a function")
  }
  count <- length(substitute(fn)[[2]])
  do.call(fn, list(...)[1:count])
}
```

Or is better way? I have function like this:

```
fn1 <- function(a, b) {

}
fn2 <- function() {

}
```

and I want to call both of them without have error about unused argument

```
invoke(fn1, 10, 20)
invoke(fn2, 10, 20)
```

second should ignore both arguments.

Comment: In response to **So how can I get number of arguments to a function?** : Something like: `length(formals(foo))`?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885207/get-all-parameters-as-list

Comment: @akrun this is from inside of the function.

Comment: @NelsonGon perfect, you can add this as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @jcubic yes, I meant `Related` because the `formals` and other methods are also mentioned there